# TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById() not working for "Gulf Standard Time"

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

I am using below code to get time zone details for "Gulf Standard Time", but its throwing error as below

**The time zone ID 'Gulf Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.**

below is line of code i am using

```
TimeZoneInfo tZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Gulf Standard Time");
```

Can you please tell me what exactly is the issue in code, as i have checked and its correct time zone name.

Comment: `Gulf Standard Time` isn't a valid timezone id.

Comment: You could use one of these though: `Arabian Standard Time`,
`Astrakhan Standard Time`, 
`Azerbaijan Standard Time`, 
`Russia Time Zone 3`, 
`Mauritius Standard Time`, 
`Saratov Standard Time`, 
`Georgian Standard Time`, 
`Caucasus Standard Time`

Comment: See following : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values

Comment: @jdweng - That page needs to be killed with fire.  It is not a maintained list, and was from Windows CE embedded.

Comment: Ok.  This one is 2017 instead of 2009 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones

Comment: @jdweng - That one is current, but only lists the default time zone for each country, not all time zones on the machine.  It describes using `tzutil` for that purpose instead.   There isn't currently a page by Microsoft that is actively maintained which lists all of the time zones.  There's the [CLDR windows time zone mapping](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) file, but that is non authoritative.

Comment: I've tried to find that page at msdn a lot of times and failed.  The one at Wiki lists all timezones.  I searched in the msdn reference source and it doesn't look like it is part of Net.  It is part of windows and there is no source for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, `"Gulf Standard Time"` isn't a valid Windows time zone identifier.

Gulf Standard Time usually refers to UTC+04:00 with no DST, as observed in the United Arab Emirates and Oman, [as described here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/gst).  The corresponding time zone in Windows appears with an English display name of `(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat`, and has a corresponding ID of `Arabian Standard Time`.

Thus in .NET:

```
TimeZoneInfo tZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Arabian Standard Time");
Console.WriteLine(tzone.DisplayName);

// prints:  (UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat
```

To get a list of supported time zones, use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` in your .NET code, and examine the `Id` and `DisplayName` properties.  Alternatively, you can call `TZUTIL /L` on the command line to list them.

Also, just to point out that this all assumes you are running on Windows.  If you are actually running .NET Core on non-Windows systems (Linux, OSX, etc.), then you should uses IANA time zone IDs.  In this case, either `"Asia/Dubai"`, or `"Asia/Muscat"` would be appropriate.

And if your code might run both on Windows and Non-Windows systems, then you will need to take advantage of my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.